# Ruby loops random outputs

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, random

So i'm writing a simple program that generates 20 sentences based on randomly selecting a verb, noun, preposition, and article from separate arrays.  Basically i have 4 separate arrays with 5 words each pertaining to a respective part of speech.

I have a loop set to run 20 times, which displays a sentence containing a word or two at random from each array.  The problem I currently have is that the program is simply generating 20 instances of the same sentence, rather than 20 different random sentences.  My loop statement currently looks like this:

```
20.times do
puts article[randarticle].capitalize + "\s" + noun[randnoun] + "\s" + verb[randverb
] + "\s" + prep[randprep] + "\s" + article[randarticle2] + "\s" + noun[randnoun2] 
+ "."
end
```

I know this is not the correct syntax for what i want, but i cannot seem to figure it out.  Any and all help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What's the `"\s"` all about? That meta character is used for scanning white space in a regex. You probably just want a space `" "`. In your `20.times` loop you need to change your variables (*e.g.*, `randarticle`, `randnoun`, etc) each time through the loop. Otherwise, they are always the same each time through.

Comment: We can't tell if `randarticle`, etc. are variables that were set outside the loop, or function calls. If the former, then set them *inside* the loop.

Comment: Show a little more code. How is `randarticle` defined or set (no need to repeat for all of them - I guess they all look very similar)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all articles, verbs etc. in arrays it is as simple as:

```
20.times do
  puts [articles, nouns, verbs, preps, articles, nouns].map(&:sample).join(' ').capitalize + '.' 
end
```